# Angular 9 : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/desktopbackup/grains/index.jpg

Tags: angular, angular5, angular9

I am creating small angular application where in i am displaying the image from local folder.
but while loading page i am getting below error

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/desktopbackup/grains/index.jpg. img tag in component.html file as below

```
 <img class="dashboadImage" [src]="sanitizeImageUrl()" alt="Card image cap">
```

in component.ts file i have

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

in constructor i have injected DomSanitizer

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

sanitizeImageUrl(): SafeUrl {
 return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("D:/desktopbackup/grains/index.jpg");
}
```

i have read several article to use local resource in angular , every where i got the samething, but i am still getting error 
"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/desktopbackup/grains/index.jpg"

Please help me.

Comment: Why are you loading in that manner?

Comment: cant you keep your images in assets folder..?

Comment: I need to display images from other project.other project will keep the image file in that folder , and from that folder i have to display on UI using angular project , thas why i can not put inside assets folder.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't access local resources like this as the browser will restrict the access to it. Rather you should put the image file inside the "assets" folder inside your Angular project. The assets folder will be available inside your angular project like below,

`Angular Project
|_ src
     |_ assets`

So, in your case if the grains folder is placed inside assets then you can refer it like below,
`<img class="dashboadImage" src="assets/grains/index.jpg" alt="Card image cap">`

Comment: I can put inside assets folder, it works fine, but my requirement is to display images from other folder which is outside of project root folder

Comment: In that case, the image should be in the server not in the local machine of the user. Deploy it a web server and try to access it using server url ("http://localhost:1111/grains/index.jpg"). PS: Make sure you handle the domains properly or else you might end up with cross domain error while accessing the resource.